# How modify selectedIndex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dimensional array, example `var TZa = new Array("Pacific/Wallis;WFT-12", "Pacific/Wallis;WFT-12")`

First value is placed into `<select id="stzone"><option></option></select>`, 
second value (after semicolon) is placed to `<input type="text" id="timezone" >`

Old code which was working correct is as below:

```
function SelChng() {
    Sel = document.getElementById("stzone");
    Inpt = document.getElementById("timezone");
    Inpt.disabled = !(Sel.value == "extended");
    Inpt.value = TZa[Sel.selectedIndex];
}
```

New code is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var input = $("#timezone").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#stzone").on("change", function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "extended") {
            input.attr("disabled", false);
        } else {
            input.attr("disabled", true);
        }
        input.val() = TZa[(this).selectedIndex];
    });
});
```

and do not change value from `input type="text"` according to array.

Please, give some idea to repair my code?

Comment: I do not understand what your question is?..

Comment: that's not how you make arrays in JavaScript. `var TZa = ["Pacific/Wallis;WFT-12", "Pacific/Wallis;WFT-12"];`. Do not use the Array constructor, JS has an array literal you should use instead.

Comment: A two dimensional array looks like this `var 2DArray = [[1,2],[3,4]];`

Comment: `input.val(TZa[(this).selectedIndex]);` .. or `input.val($(this).val());`; or `input[0].value = this.value;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the second piece of code work like the first piece of code, I think your issue is with jQuery:

```
input.val() = TZa[(this).selectedIndex];
```

Looks like it should be:

```
input.val(TZa[this.selectedIndex]);
```

See how to set values with `val()` at [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about "first value" and "Second value", so use that?

```
var TZa = [
  { area: "Pacific", location: "Wallis", wft: -12 },
  { area: "Pacific", location: "Wallis", wft: -12 }
];
```

And then walk your TZa array:

```
function buildMyData(data, index) {
  // build new HTML elements with data.area, data.location and data.wft
}
TZa.forEach(buildMyData);
```

That's not a direct answer, but it's going to make whatever it is you're really doing (and your question is very unclear on what that is), much easier.

Comment: I want to replace this line `Inpt.value = TZa[Sel.selectedIndex];` using the jQuery. I can not change format of array

Comment: and the problem is where? There are lots of examples of how to get the value from a `<select>` using jQuery, and equally many examples of how to set a value on an `<input>`. This is basic Google, what do you need stackoverflow for here?